# Pdf is not displayed using ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

Tags: angular, pdf.js, ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

I am trying to display the pdf using [ngx-extended-pdf-viewer](https://pdfviewer.net/intro). I have saved pdf under asset folder with name example.pdf and my page route is  http://localhost:4200/tool/showpdf but when angular loads the page it is not finding the pdf.

```
      <div class="pane-content">
        <ngx-extended-pdf-viewer [src]="'assets/example.pdf'" useBrowserLocale="true" height="80vh"></ngx-extended-pdf-viewer>
      </div>
```

I am getting following error in chrome debug window

```
    PDF.js v2.3.200 (build: 4ae3f9fc)
    Message: Missing PDF "http://localhost:4200/tool/assets/example.pdf".
```

looks like it is getting the path from current route. is the way to ignore the path from current route?

Answer (score 2):

1. make sure you imported the NgxExtendedPdfViewerModule module in to your relevant module
2. if number 1 doesn't works - try to replace [src] with [base64Src] and put base 64 demo value just to see if it works.
3. if number 2 doesn't work maybe you have an asynchronous problems with the loading.

Answer (score 1):

*Update September 26, 2021*:
Please update to version 10.0.0 of ngx-extended-pdf-viewer. It solves the bug.

*Original answer:*

You're right. You've found a bug. I hope I'll be able to fix it with version 10. Here's the corresponding bug ticket: https://github.com/stephanrauh/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/issues/813#issuecomment-911952618